# Ideas to reinforce piping shelter structure

Tags: frame, weather-resistant

I have bought a motorcycle shelter that is likely to blow away in a storm. I'm looking for a couple of ideas to make this a bit more permanent. My main concern is the tent hitting any parked cars around me, but ideally I'd like to make it more structurally sound. The car park it's in is at least partially sheltered from the wind. I'm very much spitballing here as I have little experience in this field. This is the shelter frame [image: shelter]:

My initial thoughts:

- Spray the whole thing in galvo spray to give it a bit more weather
  protection (I live near the sea so rust will be an issue)
- Bolt the entire thing to a heavy plank of wood - not just using the
  cross plate (which I imagine will not have much strength, but also
  with some saddle brackets. I can't bolt this to the concrete as I
  rent, so it would have to be structurally sound enough to hold the
  bolts (and I'll weigh it down with sand bags), thinking some kind of
  structural plywood?
- The top sections of the frame pipes come off, and I was thinking of
  using some expanding foam, or maybe some sand, to fill it in and
  reinforce the angles to minimise the lateral flex.
- On a similar note, I have bought some p clips and metal bracket
  things to create a kind of cross section support across the right
  angle, again to minimise the flex.

The tent section looks like this 
[image]
and so far the only thing I can think is to spray with waterproofing...It's quite thick, but the Australian sun is absolutely brutal so I'm sure there's additional things I can do perhaps?

Comment: Find 4 lead blocks - two close to middle and two corners, last longer and easier to control cf sandbags.

Comment: And attaching cords from the loops to the lead blocks could help reduce flexing.

Comment: How much do lead blocks cost? How much to properly dispose of them when you no longer want them? Use concrete blocks or 1 ft sq pavers. This shelter is not meant to resist strong winds.

Answer (score 1):

I have that structure for a trike. The tubing is galvanized steel electrical conduit and has held up relatively well for the last ten years. The fabric is not doing so well in the sun. I'm on the third replacement and it's become ragged and deteriorating. Unfortunately, I've not found a coating which will provide additional protection (yet).

The cross brace on my shelter is different, consisting of two plates. It's similar to what yours would be if you chopped the center flat portion away. I own, which allowed me to use concrete anchors.

The shelter has held up structurally through three hurricanes during the last decade. You cannot attach the moving portion to the ground on a permanent basis, obviously, but for storm situations, a temporary clamping method would be beneficial. I usually backed a motor vehicle until it was over the lowest "ring" of the shelter. This prevented it from flying upward during the storms.

If you attempt to add weights to portions of the structure other than the base, it should be noted that there will be distribution of the weight through the fabric attachment, which may exceed the strength of the fabric, especially as it ages. I can push my finger through almost any part of the existing canvas. Recent movement of the lifting portion also has torn some of the fabric.

Your idea of sandbags on the cross brace is sound, as well as any other weights attached to p-brackets. If you have room inside the enclosure, lining the perimeter with brackets and concrete blocks will provide additional security.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is quite old, but, since it doesn't have an accepted answer yet...

It appears to me that the flat brace across the bottom of the main frame is where you park the front tire of the motorcycle, thus using the weight of the bike to hold the frame down.

If you want something more to hold it down, I'd suggest cutting a 4-6" (10-15 cm) piece of plywood several in/cm longer than the frame is wide. Use a couple of conduit clamps to hold the frame down to the plywood. Locate the plywood so that when you park the bike on it, the rear wheel is on the plywood. (Conduit clamps like this):
[image]

<sup>Image provided by Lowes.com. No affiliation or endorsement intended or implied</sup>

Screws would *probably* be sufficient to hold the conduit clamps to the plywood. If you're not comfortable with that, drill the plywood then run bolts through and attach with nuts. I'd add some washers to help spread the stress across more of the plywood (but only if I was over engineering with bolts in the first place).

Since this will lift the frame off the ground by the thickness of the plywood, I'd also recommend a second piece of plywood (held down with another set of conduit clamps) under the "back" end of the frame so that you don't risk bending the piping as you roll the bike over this section to park it in place.

If you feel you need additional weight beyond the 100+ kilo of the bike, you can add some concrete blocks and/or sand bags to the plywood. If you *still* feel you need more weight to hold it down, add more concrete blocks/sand bags to the existing front  cross-piece. If you're not confident that it will stay attached in strong winds, add another piece of plywood under this cross brace (so it's not floating in the air and trying to support the front tire of the bike) and hold it in place with more conduit clamps.